# Unable to access any site pages on SharePoint Online subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a site that we are unable to see any site pages in.  We can navigate to the Site Contents page, but all other site pages state "Sorry, something went wrong."

I'm using a SharePoint Administrator account so I should be able to see the pages.  I am unable to look at the permissions on this site due to me not being able to access any site pages.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable publishing feature? Does this issue only happen on one site? What about other site?

Go to site settings > Site Pages library> Library Setting > Permission for this document library, check if this library has unique permission.

Test in another browser like chrome. Or run in compatibility mode of IE.